# Google Glass Camera Autofocus?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I read [this article](http://www.ubergizmo.com/2013/04/google-glass-has-autofocus-5-megapixel-camera/), which claims Google glass can autofocus. However, this code returns false:

`getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_AUTOFOCUS)`

I could not find a definite answer on Google Glass [Tech specs](https://support.google.com/glass/answer/3064128?hl=en). Does anyone know for sure if the camera can auto focus? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current Glass camera has a fixed focus, not autofocus. So it would make sense that this returns false.

Comment: Like you mentioned, I found GDK [issue 303](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=303): requesting additional camera focus modes (with auto focus) has been accepted but not yet implemented. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you run

```
List<String> FocusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
```

Then you will get a list of only one focus. It actually only supports

```
Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_INFINITY
```